# Are Deployment Slots supported when deploying Azure Functions from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I built a very simple Azure Function in Node.js using Visual Studio Code. I also created a new Function App from the Azure Portal and created a "Staging" deployment Slot. Now I want to deploy my function from Visual Studio Code to this existing Function App and Slot - I can't! I do not find the way to select the Slot, and any deployment will go straight into the default/Production slot.

Is this supported from VS Code? If not, is it possible to do it from VS 2017 (remember that this is a Node.js project) ?

Thanks in advance

Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure function slot is a preview version. It seems not supported in VS code, after creating a slot in the portal, there will not be a slot option and will be an error in it, like the screenshot. If not, there is normal. May be it's a bug. When deploying, it happens like you mentioned.

[image]

In the VS 2017, it works fine, just create the profile and publish your function.

[image]

**Update**:

My function is C#. Currently there is no Node.js function template in VS, but you could create c# function and write the function file with node.js manually and publish to azure function slot.

You could create it like the screenshot below, and set `Copy if newer` for the `function.json` and `index.js`.

[image]

Check it in the portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy, what type of project you need to create for the function in VS 2017?  In mine I only see support for functions projects in c#, not Node.js. I even added Node.js support without luck.

Comment: @JoseParra You could see my update. Besides, I do not recommend you to use this way. If you want to publish your node.js function to azure, I recommend you to use Kudu console to do it, you just need to upload your function files using drag and drop.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It just shows how to give up and do it in Visual Studio.

Comment: @mwilson Because several months ago, it may be a bug. And he has mentioned `If not, is it possible to do it from VS 2017?` in his question, so my solution answers his question. Could you look into the question carefully before you downvoting the answer??